# REQUEST_URI on a numeric value

Tags: php

I have searched and not been able to find anything for this question on this site, so please excuse me if it comes out as a duplicate.

I have the following url

http://mysite.com/art/1355

and I want to write a php code in the navigation so that if the user is on any page with a "numeric id" at the end, it shows a link.

here is the code, I am not sure what i have to type in for 'abc' to make this work.

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'abc')) { 
    echo "<a href="#"class="playing">viewing</a>"; 
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is numeric, display the link? Why not `if(is_numeric($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']){ echo "<a href="#"class="playing">viewing</a>" };`

Comment: can you show us a sample of a "page with a "numeric id" at the end"?

Comment: @ngen tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: Well...what does $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] equal?

Comment: Sorry, try this `if(is_numeric($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){ echo "<a href="#"class="playing">viewing</a>" };`

Comment: @ngen still not working... fyi the original link is mysite.com/art/p.php?id=1805 I have written a rewrite rule in .htaccess to change it to mysite.com/art/1805 not sure if that has anything to do with this or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use regular expression to check it:

```
if (preg_match('/\/[0-9]+$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
{
    echo '<a href="#" class="playing">viewing</a>';
}
```